# interchange column values on an single update (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, sql-update

We need to scramble some fields values on some table, but there is a logical link between some fields.

For example, if the table is:   table t(name varchar2(30), email varchar2(60)),
the email values must start with the complete value of the name:

```
Name        Email
----        ----
Smith       Smitha@any.com
```

So after the scramble, it can be

```
Name        Email
----        ----
xubal       xubaly@any.com
```

We use the dbms_random.string function, so for every call it return a distinct value.

It's possible on one unique run to make the update and to keep the logical link between the fields? (I can't use db triggers)

On the next two options that I tried, Oracle return the old value of the name field and not the new value.

```
update t
set name=dbms_random.string('l',length(name)),
    email=name || dbms_random.string('l',2) || '@any.com';

update t t1
set name=dbms_random.string('l',length(name)),
    email=(select t1.name || dbms_random.string('l',2) || '@any.com'
           from t t2
           where t2.rowid = t1.rowid)
```

Answer (score 2):

With `MERGE` you can do this with a query rather than a procedure.

Get a list of table `t` row identifiers (using the Oracle `ROWID` pseudocolumn) and the random names, then match them back up to table `t` and use them to update both the name and the email. The query (which I've tested) is as follows:

```
MERGE INTO t
USING (
  SELECT ROWID AS ID, DBMS_Random.String('l', LENGTH(name)) AS RandName
  FROM t) newNames
ON (t.ROWID = newNames.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    name = newNames.RandName,
    email = newNames.RandName || SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a package and use a variable in the package.
Something like this:

```
create package pck as

v t.name%TYPE;
function rnd_next(in_name t.name%TYPE) return t.name%TYPE;
function rnd_cur return t.name%TYPE;
end;
/

create package body pck as

function rnd_next(in_name t.name%TYPE) return t.name%TYPE is

begin
v := dbms_random.string('l',length(in_name));
return v;
end;

function rnd_cur return t.name%TYPE is

begin
return v;
end;
end;
/
```

Then you can update like this:

```
update t
set name = pck.rnd_next(name),
email = pck.rnd_cur || '@aaa.com';
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e5e5/1)